# Labels are not displayed on the chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Yesterday was to update the library highcharts. After the update I have a problem with labels on the chart. Only one label (first serie in data) appeared on the chart. For all that labels are not displayed are added html property: visilibty="hidden".

For example:

[jsfiddle](http://goo.gl/dH7mfq)

Anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Try to add the `plotOptions.series.dataLabels.allowOverlap` option.

[I edited your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/95k3kxqz/3/)